# Is there a way to use CRA with a PHP backend?

Tags: reactjs, apache, webpack, webpack-dev-server, create-react-app

I am trying to set up the CRA environment in a way, so that I can use php files instead of the provided index.html.

Initially, I proxied requests to my MAMP server as it is [advised](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development) in the CRA-docs, however, I want to do some server-side processing *before* I run any react file in order to add some `<meta/>` tags for crawlers which don't have JavaScript enabled. (**Note:** My main apache server is unable to pre-render any JS files)

Before using react, webpack or CRA I achieved this with `gulp-connect-php` as the dev server which read from a pre-bundled dist folder and `browser-sync` for implementing hot-reloading.